# Add additional bar lines in highcharts x axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have one chart in my application.I have to customize that chart like below image
[image]

here everything working fine but how to draw that bar lines in x axis,whether it is possible or not.I am adding one fiddler can anyone help me to draw that bar line with every bar

code

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    }]
});
```

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/renjithgovind/tcr8rrrh/)

Comment: If you mean the dashed line underneath the bars, then I don't believe that's possible natively in HighCharts. You'd have to fudge together some element underneath and use CSS on that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: if there is any way to find the bar height in highchart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw those lines with the [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.path). To access points's graphic attribute like height, width,x, y use `chart.series[seriesIndex].data[pointIndex].shapeArgs`

```
function getLinePaths(chart) {
  var series = chart.series,
    extensionFactor = 0.3,
    linePaths = [];

  series[series.length - 1].data.forEach(function(point) {
    var shapeArgs = point.shapeArgs,
      left = chart.plotLeft + shapeArgs.x,
      right = left + shapeArgs.width,
      y = chart.plotTop + shapeArgs.y + shapeArgs.height,
      length = right - left;

    linePaths.push([
      'M', left - (length * extensionFactor), y,
      'L', right + (length * extensionFactor), y
    ]);
  });

  return linePaths;
}

function renderLines() {
  var chart = this,
    customLines = this.customLines = [],
    linePaths = getLinePaths(chart);

  linePaths.forEach(function(linePath) {
    customLines.push(
      chart.renderer.path(linePath)
      .attr({
        'stroke-width': 3,
        stroke: 'red',
        zIndex: 6
      })
      .add()
    );
  });
}

function animateLines() {
  var chart = this,
    customLines = chart.customLines,
    linePaths = getLinePaths(chart);

  customLines.forEach(function (line, i) {
    line.animate({
      d: linePaths[i]
    });
  });
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/tcr8rrrh/1/

If you do not want to use renderer, then add those line as series.

```
series: [
{
  type: 'line',
  data: [[-0.3, 0], [0.3, 0]],
  color: 'red'
}],

plotOptions: {
  line: {
    marker: {
        enabled: false
    },
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    showInLegend: false
  }
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/tcr8rrrh/2/

Comment: Thank u so much... can u tell how to draw that two L shaped lines in this,initially i thought we can put 2 additional div with borders will solve this problem but i need to show y axis in chart then my logic will not work...

Comment: You can render 'L' line in the same manner as the rest of the lines. Use chart.plotLeft, chart.plotTop, chart.plotWidth and chart.plotHeight to get corners coordinates. http://jsfiddle.net/s3hqvvm6/ They should be also be moved on redraw events so they will be responsive (in my example bottom lines are responsive, 'L' line is not)

Comment: Thanks...what is the use of animateLines() here because it is working fine without this function,i am a beginner in highchart